# I'm currently building a chrome extension using javascript. I need script i , **Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined Context background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I'm currently building a chrome extension using javascript. I need to run a script to get the input element of the active tab, so in my background/index.js file, I tried to do a document.querySelector("#subBtn") but I received:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined
Context
background.js
Stack Trace
background.js:1 (anonymous function)**

```
const subBtn = document.querySelector("#subBtn");
const resetBtn = document.querySelector('.reset');
const intputPart = document.querySelector("#form");

window.resetBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    intputPart.style.display = "block";
    location.reload();

})
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome extensions don't run in the context of the web page, so they don't have a global `document` variable.

If you want to modify the DOM of the current page, you can use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/).